# Conjugation of Quaternions as Rotations in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: rotations, quaternions

In a lot of published texts, when I read about the conjugacy class of pure quaternions being rotations, they assume that the norm of the non-pure quaternion is 1.  Is there a reason that this is necessary?  Doesn't the conjugacy map preserve length of the pure quaternion it's rotating no matter what since the norm of a quaternion is the reciprocal of the norm of its inverse?  Or is it just that this assumption about the norm gives some nicer looking resultant pure quaternion?

Comment: I don't know the theory.  And I don't know what "conjugacy map" means.  But I do regularly use quaternions to represent 3d rotations.  If the rotating quaternion is not normalized, it may scale the vector you're rotating.  The vector itself, however, can be any length without any issues.  But if it's a unit-length vector, then it happens to look just like a regular unit-length quaternion during the rotation, which probably makes it easier, in a text, to illustrate how the quaternion/conjugate sandwich multiplication produces a pure rotation of the augmented 3d vector.

Comment: @JCooper: the map $q\to w^{-1}qw$ is a [conjugation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_automorphism); the norm of $w$ doesn't matter in that unit quaternions are sent to unit quaternions regardless.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that whatever you're reading simply defined $q\to w^{-1}qw$ with $\|w\|=1$ in order to buckle down on redudancy. Since conugation with $w$ is independent of $\|w\|$ (so long as its nonzero), we can parametrize the family of conjugations with unit quaternions nicely and know that no two parameters represent the same conjugation.

Comment: @JCooper is actually right — as is anon.  It's just an unfortunate difference of terminology.  See my answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is just that there's a slightly different meaning to "conjugation" when using unit quaternions.  You are correct in that mathematicians mean something like $R v R^{-1}$ when they say "conjugation" in the context of group theory.  And while the unit quaternions do form a group, the quaternions also form a [$^*$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/*-algebra) — basically generalizing the concept of complex conjugation.

Thus, when discussing quaternions (or more general geometric algebras), when people talk about conjugation, they frequently mean just $R v \bar{R}$, where $\bar{R}$ is the quaternion conjugate (or reverse in more general geometric algebras).  The reason they do this is that for a *unit* quaternion
\begin{equation}
  R^{-1} = \frac{\bar{R}} {\lVert R \rVert^2}.
\end{equation}
But of course, if $\lVert R \rVert = 1$, there's no difference.  And the quaternion conjugate is slightly easier to compute (just flip the sign of the "vector" part) than the inverse (which also requires computing and dividing by the squared norm).  So quaternion users frequently conflate the two operations.  Personally, I prefer to call $R v R^{-1}$ conjugation and $R v \bar{R}$ "sandwiching".

You are also correct that true conjugation will necessarily preserve the norm of the object being conjugated.  A related important fact is that "sandwiching" a vector by a general quaternion necessarily preserves the vectorial nature.  That is, if $v$ is a pure vector quaternion (the scalar part is zero), then $R v \bar{R}$ is also a pure vector.

For what it's worth, in practice I actually find better numerical results at negligible cost if I use $R v R^{-1}$.  As long as I can ensure that $R \neq 0$, this works out much better all around.  But it is occasionally easier to do analysis with sandwiching.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving anon's comment as a CW answer to get this off the list of unanswered questions.

If $r$ is a non-zero real number, it makes no difference whether you conjugate with $w$ a
or $wr$. This is because all the quaternions commute with $r$ so
$$
wqw^{-1}=wqrr^{-1}w^{-1}=wrqr^{-1}w^{-1}=(wr)q(wr)^{-1}.
$$
Therefore we are at liberty to conjugate with $w/\|w\|$ instead of $w$, and may assume that $\|w\|=1$.